# CSS is not applied to an element

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and busy with an example that I cannot figure out.
I want to have the background of my element 'active' in the color green.
The element is a link in a navigation menu.

[This is the HTML content of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q9vM.png)


[And here is the CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMU8b.png)

Could you please let me know, what i did wrong so i can learn from it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: post real code, and not images of.

Comment: In your case you only need to target the class. The style rules are valid, verify that these styles aren't being over-qualified by another style rule with more specificity. Also, verify that the `a` element hasn't got any of it's own style rules declared, like `background-color`.
You should also take full advantage of code snippets in future when posting questions of this nature so that we can see the code, replicate the issue and be of better assistance to you, as well as making it worthwhile for us; taking the time to help address and resolve your issue.

Comment: @Spanhaak   I think I solved your problem, see my answer

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, thanks for your feedback! First post. Will try in the future.

Comment: you see those downvotes? ask yourself why you got them; a: a few reasons and one of which is what I outlined first. Stack pro tip: post actual code, it goes faster for everyone.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its my first time here.... i guess people think learning goes faster when you bash them.

Comment: I told you what to do in my first comment; you call that bashing? Did you see my comment was upvoted and more than once? I think it spoke for itself, yet you didn't do what I asked; that's how things go here on Stack. I hope you'll remember this if/when you post another question. When you post actual code/fiddle, people can better help you and in testing it, rather than having to retype code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i will use real actual code the next time, its just i did not know. I saw i could share with an image, so i did. I understand that send the actual code is better. That is what i have learned. My reference to bashing was related to the down votes, not to your comment.

Comment: It's a shame that your first experience on Stack wasn't a good one and I for one am really a pretty nice guy, least I consider myself to be and my friends also. Everyone here (on Stack) wants people to have a good/friendly experience and are always ready to help :) If you think of this; had you hundreds lines of code and the problem may have been inside 50%+, it's not a good experience for others in having to retype all of it and to test it. Put yourself in other people's shoes and you'll see what I mean, I hope you can appreciate that.

Comment: Addendum to my above comment: Copy/paste your code in the editor, highlight the code and hit the CTRL-K keys, or the "code" tab; it will automatically indent your code. If you do that (now, later here), the downvotes may get removed if others are still inside your question and checking to see if an update was made. This will also help future readers to the question.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting background of `li` element but the `a` tag is over it. so use this instead:

```
li.active a{
  background-color:#00CC33;
  color:blue;
  border-color:#00CC33;
}
```

Comment: @Spanhaak  I think this would solve your question. If yes then please do accept my answer by clicking on the checkbox on the left of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot KittyCat!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class like you are you need to use .active instead of #active. Using # indicates an id not a class.